# Maven plugins in WebApp and deploying

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, plugins, glassfish

I'm using Maven in a JavaEE project. I splited my project into some modules : webapp (view+controler), business, persistence, model.

I'm asking :

--> Do I have to put my maven plugins glassfish into the pom.xml of the web app only or put it into the parent project pom.xml ? 
I don't understand properly how it works in this case because I have several moduls.

Also, how to deploy it ? I used `mvn package glassfish:deploy` But come with it the question about where do I have to make it : only in the webapp or in the parent project ?

Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put the maven-glassfish-plugin only on the web app module. It doesn't make sense ( to me ) to configure that plugin in the parent module.

Then I would package and deploy with two separate command:

```
parentDir$ mvn clean package
parentDir$ mvn -f webappDir glassfish:deploy
```

or if you prefer:

```
parentDir$ mvn clean package && mvn -f webappModuleDir glassfish:deploy
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now it's more clear.
However, when using Eclipse IDE and restarting my server it blocks on the process "Restarting Glassfish myDomain". 
But when using the command line there's no bug. Do you have an idea ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I switched to IntelliJ since several years ago

Comment: Ok now I'm using JPA with EJB3. 
My question is about the file persistence.xml. Do I have to put it into the persistence module (where my DAO is defined) or in the webapp module ?

Comment: This is a new argument, you should create a new question and you should also flag this question if it has been answered.

Comment: Anyway, think to your question, who is the module that require the persistence? The EJB module or the web app module that consumes the EJB?

Comment: Ok sorry I'll do.
Actually it's the EJB module who needs the persistence so logically I have to put only into the EJB module right ?

Comment: Exactly, consider also that the EJB module could be deployed on a different  container from the web app.

Comment: @Khama, if the question has been answered, could you please mark it as solved?